# Does GCC merge files compiled together?

Tags: gcc, inline

Let's say that you have `prog.c` that includes `lib.h`, whose functions are defined in `lib.c`, and you build the program with ̀`gcc -O3 lib.c prog.c`.

Does GCC merge both source files before compiling them?

Is GCC able to inline short functions of `lib.c` into the resulting binary?

## Summary of answers

This does the trick: `gcc -flto -O3 lib.c prog.c`.

Both source files are still compiled individually, but the linker is able to inline functions from one file into the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does GCC merge both source files before compiling them?

No, it doesn't

> Is GCC able to inline short functions of lib.c into the resulting binary?

Yes, at advanced optimization level. Look at Whole Program Optimization, Link Time Optimization and similar options